# HTML button link: Hit endpoint but do not open page

Tags: javascript, html, button, hyperlink

I have a button similar to:

`<button onclick="window.location='http://www.example.com';">Visit Page Now</button>`

I would like the click of the button to send a request to the endpoint but not open a new window or new tab. Is this possible?

Comment: i think you should looking for `ajax`. This example is very similar to yours: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Comment: Use `fetch` if you want to target modern browsers.

Comment: Thanks for that link @Bitcollage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to make the request. You'd have to change your markup a bit

```
<button onclick="hitEndpoint('http://www.example.com')">Visit Page Now</button>
```

Then later on in the script section of your page you could write something like:

```
function hitEndpoint(url){
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      //we're done making the request
      if(this.readyState === 4) {
         //status code was successful
         if(this.status === 200) {
            console.log("hit endpoint successfully")
         } else {
            console.log("error hitting endpoint");
         }
      }
   };
   xhttp.open("GET", url);
   xhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery ajax method to send request without loading the whole page

```
   $.ajax({
   url:'sendrequest.php',
   type:'post',
   data:{id:id},
   datatype:'json',
   success:function(data){

          }
     )};
```